# Find multiples of a number in list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a list and I want to find all the multiples of that number within a certain tolerance as well as get their indices:

```
def GetPPMError(t, m):
    """
    calculate theoretical (t) and measured (m) ppm
    """
    return (((t - m) / t) * 1e6)

multiple = n*1.0033
a = 100 
b = [100, 101, 101.0033,102, 102.0066,102.123,103.0099]

results = [p for p in b if abs(GetPPMError(a,b)) < 10]
```

So I want to find all the multiples like `102.0066` and `103.0099` etc. 
where `a = 100 + 1*1.0033`, `a = 100 + 2*1.0033`, `a = 100 + 3*1.0033` etc

So the result would be the indexes.

Results for the indexes:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

and:

```
[101.0033, 102.0066, 103.0099]
```

for the values.

Comment: What is `n` and `intensitySortedPeaks` - please read [MCVE]. Note: you can avoid the issues with floating point arithmetic if you use `decimal.Decimal`

Comment: sorry that was an error it should be 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for your data:

```
multiple = 1.0033
a = 100 
digits = 6

res = []
res_index = []
for n, x in enumerate(b):
    diff = round((x - a) / multiple, digits)
    if diff != 0 and diff == int(diff):
        res.append(x)
        res_index.append(n)
print(res)
print(res_index)
```

Output:

```
[101.0033, 102.0066, 103.0099]
[2, 4, 6]
```